# Geoserver does not wrap GRIB raster points to coordinates where x < 0

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, grib

I am new to the GeoServer and want to use it for plotting wind barbs based on a GRIB file over land data.

The wind barbs are properly created but nothing is shown on coordinates x < 0.
The map data has bounds (for x) of -180 - 180 whereas the grib data contains values between 0 - 360. Shouldn't the Geoserver be able to handle the wrapping? At least for the land data it works...

Here is an image of the results I get:

[image]

The strange thing is, that when I zoom out completely, the wrapping seems to work fine:
[image]

Can you hint me in any direction whether my data is wrong, the layer is not defined correctly or if it is an issue with the style declaration?

EDIT:

In my style definition for the wind barbs, I specify the spatial resolution for different zoom levels for the raster  as follows:

```
<ogc:Function name="parameter">
    <ogc:Literal>scale</ogc:Literal>
    <ogc:Function name="Categorize">
        <ogc:Function name="env">
            <ogc:Literal>wms_scale_denominator</ogc:Literal>
        </ogc:Function>
        <ogc:Literal>64</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>100000</ogc:Literal>

        <ogc:Literal>32</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>500000</ogc:Literal>

        <ogc:Literal>8</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>1000000</ogc:Literal>

        <ogc:Literal>2.0</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>5000000</ogc:Literal>

        <ogc:Literal>0.8</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>10000000</ogc:Literal>

        <ogc:Literal>0.4</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>20000000</ogc:Literal>

        <ogc:Literal>0.3</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>60000000</ogc:Literal>


        <ogc:Literal>0.1</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>70000000</ogc:Literal>

        <ogc:Literal>0.07</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>140000000</ogc:Literal>

        <ogc:Literal>0.05</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Function>
</ogc:Function>
```

Also I found out, that when I convert the grib file into a geoTiff with

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326  inputGrib.grb output.tif --config CENTER_LONG 0 -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=100
```

everything works as expected.

EDIT 2020-02-26
This behavior is caused by a bug [as described on the geotools issue tracker](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-6313?).
It will be fixed in GeoTools v22.3 which is used in Geoserver v1.17 will be released in March 2020.
Unfortunately, wrapping still fails for wms requests with output format application/pdf and image/svg+xml.