# Control RasterAsPointCollection plotting granularity for the GeoServer in SDL file?

Tags: raster, geoserver, sld

I  am using the geoserver to create windcharts. This works perfectly fine, except that the data is not plotted in a clean grid, i.e. the granularity of the wind barbs along the vertical axis is a lot higher than along the horizontal one:

[image]

My weather datasource is a GeoTiff in EPGS:4326, the windchart is in EPSG:4326 as well.
Is it somehow possible to control the granularity of the vertical axis and the horizontal axis separately?

The relevant section from my style sheet is:

```
....
<ogc:Function name="ras:RasterAsPointCollection">
    <ogc:Function name="parameter">
        <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Function>
    <!-- Activate the logic to recognize the emisphere -->
    <ogc:Function name="parameter">
        <ogc:Literal>emisphere</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>True</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Function>
    <ogc:Function name="parameter">
        <ogc:Literal>interpolation</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Literal>InterpolationBilinear</ogc:Literal>
    </ogc:Function>
    <ogc:Function name="parameter">
        <ogc:Literal>scale</ogc:Literal>
        <ogc:Function name="Categorize">
            <ogc:Function name="env">
                <ogc:Literal>wms_scale_denominator</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Literal>64</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>100000</ogc:Literal>

            <ogc:Literal>32</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>500000</ogc:Literal>

            <ogc:Literal>8</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>1000000</ogc:Literal>

            <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>2500000</ogc:Literal>

            <ogc:Literal>2.0</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>5000000</ogc:Literal>

            <ogc:Literal>0.8</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>10000000</ogc:Literal>

            <ogc:Literal>0.4</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>20000000</ogc:Literal>

            <ogc:Literal>0.3</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>60000000</ogc:Literal>


            <ogc:Literal>0.1</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>70000000</ogc:Literal>

            <ogc:Literal>0.07</ogc:Literal>
            <ogc:Literal>140000000</ogc:Literal>

            <ogc:Literal>0.05</ogc:Literal>

        </ogc:Function>
    </ogc:Function>
</ogc:Function>
```

If I use another projection (e.g. EPSG:3995) I end up with a completely unusable view at the poles:

[image]

How can I control the sampling of the raster source in a way that a regular grid of points is drawn in the target projection?

**REMARK 2020-02-26**
Apparently this issue only exists for GeoTiff stores. When I switch to Grib or NetCDF format, then scaling for the vertical axis works.
Unfortunately, with those formats another issue related to wrapping exists: [Geoserver does not wrap GRIB raster points to coordinates where x < 0](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/343925/geoserver-does-not-wrap-grib-raster-points-to-coordinates-where-x-0)